# couchbase index for variable array in query

Tags: indexing, couchbase, sql++

I tried to make and run some N1QL query that find document some field is matched with element of variable array in query. but speed of the query is too slow.
The query is like below.

> select * from `bucket` where tp='type' and
>   tm between 1484618520 and 1484618615 and nm='name' and
>   checked=false and (bucket.gm in ["TEST","TEST2"])

["TEST","TEST2"] part is variable depend on condition.

I want to speedup this query.

How can I create index for this query including variable array?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this problem by using below command.

`create index new_index on bucket(gm,tp,tm,nm,checked) using gsi;`

I set the "gm" field as leading key of new index.

Then the query speed was totally improved.